# How to specify the location of the log files generated by my custom bootstrapper running embedded

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3

**Short story:** Is there a way to specify the location of the log files, other than passing it as an argument at the beginning? If no, how can I pass arguments to a bundle running embedded (on updates)?

**Long story:** To avoid the requirement of the user to provide admin rights on every update, we give them the option to install our `ElevationService`. This `Service` runs as `SYSTEM` and is used to automatically start our new bundle with `SYSTEM` rights to install it. In this case, we pass the argument `-log <path>` to the new bundle to ensure, the logs are written to the right path. By default `C:\Windows\Temp` would be used and we don't want that. So far, so good! But at the end of the bundle update the old bundle gets uninstalled. This is done embedded, and so the log files of the embedded setup instance are gonna be written to the default path (`C:\Windows\Temp`). Is there a way how we can change that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Bundle, look at:

```xml
<Log Prefix="path-to-log-file-here" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already aware of that. Please read the "long story" section in my original post, where I described the real problem.